# Calculate hours of leave taken by employee PER DAY for a week?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, jpa

So I have the following table :

```
id  approved    end_date             reason         start_date                  submitted    employee_id
1   true    "2022-02-01 22:00:00"   "sickness"  "2022-02-01 20:01:05"   "2022-05-24 10:44:57.385"   8
2   true    "2022-02-03 22:00:00"   "sickness"  "2022-02-02 20:01:05"   "2022-05-24 10:45:06.548"   8
3   true    "2022-05-31 10:00:00"   "family"    "2022-05-24 08:00:00"   "2022-05-24 16:32:40.257"   8
4   true    "2022-05-17 12:00:00"   "family"    "2022-05-17 10:30:00"   "2022-05-24 16:33:36.213"   8
5   true    "2022-05-20 08:00:00"   "family"    "2022-05-19 08:00:00"   "2022-05-24 16:34:16.09"    8
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following :

I want to retrieve the leaves taken by an employee IN THAT WEEK and have them filtered by DAY :

for example, if i want to retrieve the leaves(by hours) taken by employee_id : 8, for week [05/23,05/29] , my desired output will be something like that  :

```
monday | tuesday | wednesday | thursday | friday |saturday |sunday
0           8          8         8         8         0        0
```

and for the next week [05/30,05/05] :

```
monday | tuesday | wednesday | thursday | friday |saturday |sunday
 8          2          0           0         0        0        0
```

**8 because a day of work = 8hours**

I know this may look like i'm trying to get someone to do my work for me, but this operation is so complex and I'm kinda stuck on how I should be approaching this problem. I would appreciate some guidance on this

Answer (score 0):

Creating a manual/static pivot is how I would try to solve this problem...

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5jCTUUaEUoB9HthPrUu4RX/0

Basically you create a calculated column for a given row, in this case it's extracting the Day Of Week from the submitted column, and then counting the ID column values.

```
    select 
     
             count((CASE WHEN extract(isodow from s.submitted) = 1 THEN id END)) AS "Monday",
             count((CASE WHEN extract(isodow from s.submitted) = 2 THEN id END)) AS "Tuesday",
             count((CASE WHEN extract(isodow from s.submitted) = 3 THEN id END)) AS "Wednesday",
             count((CASE WHEN extract(isodow from s.submitted) = 4 THEN id END)) AS "Thursday",
             count((CASE WHEN extract(isodow from s.submitted) = 5 THEN id END)) AS "Friday",
             count((CASE WHEN extract(isodow from s.submitted) = 6 THEN id END)) AS "Saturday",
             count((CASE WHEN extract(isodow from s.submitted) = 7 THEN id END)) AS "Sunday"
   from stack s

Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Sunday
0       5       0           0           0       0           0
```